# How do I query codeQL central data?

Tags: codeql

I know we can go see a run status, language, run date for a repository on codeQL central. But is there an API to get the data programmatically? Or a query which we can run and see the data (not the analysis result, just when did it run, on which languages those kind of data).

Does this information pushed to kusto at any point?
scenario is:
We have list of repositories (about 400+) and we want to run some query to see which of them ran when and which of them doesn't run codeql at all.